# How to pass a string as a props and make the component read it like a variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**Enquiry**: I have one component that will fetch three different data from a json. But how do I pass a props to make that component realize which data I want to fetch?

**Example**: App.js will include three duplicates of a single component and pass different props.

```
<Component nameOfDataToBeFetched={'1'} />
<Component nameOfDataToBeFetched={'2'} />
<Component nameOfDataToBeFetched={'3'} />
```

But in a receiving component, I want to fetch data from a certain json api using that props.

```
fetch('www.example.com/api')
     .then(response => response.json)
     .then(json => setData(json.nameOfDataToBeFetched.value)
```

I mean, I can just do conditional fetching depending on the props, but is there a way to fetch a specific data using the props?

Comment: Yes, there's a way; which part of that are you having a problem with? Note that this means you'll make the same request three times; that's not very efficient, maybe you should lift the request to the parent?

Comment: Yes, I have implemented my app to make the requests and store data in the parents, but I am just curious on if I could, somehow, make the child know the data to request depending on the parent's props without conditional rendering

Comment: You can pass props to the child, and the child can use them to make and handle the request, yes. It's unclear what *problem* you've had with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this be answer to yout question?

```
// Component.js

componetDidMount(){
  const url = `example.com/api/${this.props.nameOfDataToBeFetched`;
/*
// Any other composition
 const url = `example.com/api?dataName=${this.props.nameOfDataToBeFetched`;
*/
  fetch(url)
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one component and pass different props.

```js
componetDidMount(){
  fatchData(this.props.nameToBeFetched)
}


componetDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
  if(prevProps.nameToBeFetched !== this.props.nameToBeFetched){
    fetchData(this.props.nameToBeFetched)
    }
}
async function fetchData(nameToBeFetched){
}
```